# Customize a setting?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, customize

I'm new to Emacs.  How do I customize a setting?

This is actually a generic question inspired by the `org-mode` manual:

[image]

In this description, it says to `(setq org-clock-persist 'history)`.  Where should I set this?

I'm a new user to Emacs, and I'm starting with `org-mode`. If I need to set this in the `.emacs` file, I do not know how to locate it and do it.

Step by step guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at the
[manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html)
nodes on the
[.emacs file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)
and the
[customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html)
interface to get started.  I found these resources via web searches
for
["emacs .emacs"](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+.emacs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
and ["emacs customize"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html).

Comment: The answer is available here. http://superuser.com/questions/73458/where-is-emacs-file. Somehow I have overlooked it. *BTW, Why are `emacs` questions on superuser? Where should I ask `emacs` questions then?*

Comment: @Prasanna this emacs stack exchange site did not exist when that question was asked. Now that there is a official emacs stack exchange site, all emacs related questions should be pointed here. Of course there are exceptions, but they are few in number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to post this straight forward answer which I find will be more relevant.

**In Windows(10):**
`C:\Users\$USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\.emacs`
Here

1. `\AppData\Roaming` are hidden folders, so type them in the address
   bar and Windows will show them to you as you type.
2. `$USERNAME` is your username in your computer for your login.

**In Ubuntu(Linux)**
`home\$USERNAME\.emacs`

Answer (score 2):

So your .emacs file is usually in a couple of places, unless it has been set up in an odd way. Your .emacs.el file is by default in  your home directory,or in a directory called .emacs.d. And your .emacs file should be called either .emacs.el or init.el. 
As for customizing things, simply paste the customization into your init file. But depending on the mode you're working in there is a feature called 
easy-customization that does a lot of this for you that you can get to from the menus or by calling with M-X. 
I hope that helps!